# Backup script for Windows AMI

Tags: windows, backup, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I just want to know what could you recommend a script to backup Windows server?

I tried to use the normal Amazon API command line stated below and it’s working fine. However, when I restore the snapshot file, it didn’t work correctly.

```
/opt/aws/bin/ec2-create-snapshot vol-xxxxxxxx -d "System Drive"
```

I would appreciate any recommendation for backing up Windows instance.

James

Comment: How are you "restoring the snapshot file" ?

Comment: @MattHouser, Restoration will be done by creating a new volume based on that snapshot file and register a new AMI for that volume.

Answer (score 1):

Windows AMIs cannot be created from EBS snapshots.  Only Linux AMIs can be created this way.

For Windows instances, you should create the AMI directly from the EC2 instance using

> ec2-create-image

If you want to restore an instance from an EBS volume:

1. Create a new volume from your snapshot
2. Launch a new Windows instance from an AMI that matches your original instance as much as possible
3. Stop your new instance and replace the root volume with your restored volume

Comment: when using ec2-create-image does it create EBS snapshot file and AMI? If yes, could you recommend any script that will do a clean up of EBS snapshot and de-register AMI? Thanks

Comment: By the way, for daily cleaning up of EBS snapshot, I am using ec2-prune-snapshots script which is really effective but for de-registering AMI I am looking how to do that.

Comment: Creating an AMI creates both an AMI and snapshots (one for each volume). The snapshots cannot be deleted as long as the AMI exists.

Comment: I tried to test to de-register an AMI and the snapshot is still exist. In this case I have to manually remove the snapshot.

Comment: De-registering an AMI image does not delete the snapshots.  You must delete them after de-registering your AMI image.